# Meaning of word=$word"`expr substr '${ -b :board}' 1 3`"?

Tags: bash, sh, expr

I am working on some bash scripting conversion to C++ and came across this line...

```
word="yahoo"

word=$word"`expr substr '${ -b :board}' 1 3`"
```

I understand what expr substr does, but the argument that I provide "${ -b :board}" does not make any sense to me.

When I tried to run that on terminal:

```
 echo $word
```

Output:

```
 yahoo${
```

I would appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: It is totally non-sense I believe

Comment: This is an error in my bash. If you are getting output, please check that what you posted is actually what you tried (you also have a different code in title and in body of your post). Some further context might also help, if available.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's nonsense, it's certainly code nobody should ever use. Bash's built-in facilities are far superior to `expr`, which is an antique from the 1970s present only for backwards compatibility.

Comment: As it's in single quotes it's literally the string "${ -b :board}" and the first three characters are "${ ". Append that to "yahoo" and you get "yahoo${ ".

Comment: Note also that we generally don't permit "explain this code" questions here. See [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta].

Comment: Sorry about posting on the wrong topic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this code come from? It almost looks like it's code that is generated by other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not about Bash or sh, but about `expr`, a standalone command that is part of, e.g., the GNU Coreutils. If we consult [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#String-expressions), we find

> `expr` evaluates an expression and writes the result on standard output. Each token of the expression must be a separate argument.

and

> `substr string position length`
>   Returns the substring of *`string`* beginning at *`position`* with length at most *`length`*. If either *`position`* or *`length`* is negative, zero, or non-numeric, returns the null string.

So the command

```
expr substr '${ -b :board}' 1 3
```

takes the string `${ -b :board}` and extracts a substring of length 3, starting at position 1, which is `${` .

The command

```
word=$word"`expr substr '${ -b :board}' 1 3`"
```

puts the `expr` command into a command substitution (the backticks) and appends the result to the expansion of `$word`, which at this point contains `yahoo`, so that's how you end up with `yahoo${` .

This all being said, I don't see the reason to do it like that. The output of the `expr` command is a constant string, so you could really just replace everything with

```
word='yahoo${ '
```

---

As a side note, in modern Bash, you could get the same functionality with parameter expansion:

```
word='yahoo'
var='${ -b :board}'
word+=${var:0:3}
```

But the result is the same, and without more context seems to not make any sense in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have one more question... Another line goes like this: 
word=$word"${ -s :psize}"

How would this line work then?

Comment: @PranayMarella That one makes even less sense than the original (and gives a "bad substitution" error in bash). Where on earth are you getting this?

Comment: Note that `expr` is part of the POSIX standard, and the Coreutils package just provides a particular implementation of `expr`. The `substr` command, though, *is* a GNU extension to `expr`.

Comment: @chepner Good point; `substr`, in particular, doesn't seem to be part of POSIX `expr` (using it as a string argument produces unspecified results). BSD `expr` treats it as a normal string.